# How to draw graph using core graphics

Tags: iphone

I'd like to be able to draw a graph using just the Apple Framework.

[image]

Is this possible using just CoreGraphics, or do I need to use any other framework?

I don't want to use any third party framework for drawing the graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible. A graph like that is just a line. You can use a UIBezierPath or CGPath to draw this. Typically you'd have an array of the points on your graph, then just add lines to each point when building your path.

[WWDC 2011 session 129](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=129) goes through how the graph in the Stocks app is drawn and made "fancy", all using core graphics.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a sample code to do something with CoreGraphics

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startX, startY);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, nextX, nextY);
// [...] and so on, for all line segments
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] cgColor]);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

If you want to draw axis, labels, I suggest using CorePlot http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Comment: core-plot is third party! i do not want to use third party one!

Comment: no problem, it was just suggestion to make your life easier... then just put your values into some sort of collection that suites you, iterate through it and use code from above

Comment: Ivor Prebeg!  i worked with that framework! but i need to do create my own with only include with apple frame not at all any third party stuff!   Thanks for suggestion!